# Socket hangs up on fetching mails from Gmail API using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

On fetching 50 or more emails from Gmail API using NodeJs, it says socket hang up

It works fine for a lower number of result (30 or less)
scope: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/

```
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });

gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: 'me',
        q: item,
        maxResults: 50,
      });
```

Comment: When I saw your question, it seems that `google-apps-script` tag is added. Can I ask you about the relationship between your question and `google-apps-script`?

Comment: This is not the proper scope to perform this operation, can you post the full code you are using to list these messages?